# Problems reading a file Path in spanish with pyWIN32,

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I am using win32com to convert a .docx file into a .txt file. It works well until it gets unrecognized characters in Spanish.

```
DOC_FILEPATH = r"C:\Temp\Hugo- Ortíz -.docx"
s = find_between_r(DOC_FILEPATH, '.', '')
FILETXT = DOC_FILEPATH.strip(s)
FILETXT = FILETXT + "txt"
doc = win32com.client.GetObject(DOC_FILEPATH) 
text = doc.Range().Text 
with open(FILETXT, "wb") as f:
   f.write(text.encode("utf-8"))
```

When win32com.client reads the DOC_FILEPATH, I get this error

```
moniker, i, bindCtx = pythoncom.MkParseDisplayName(Pathname)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221014, 'El moniker no puede abrir un archivo', None, None)
```

Is there a way to read that file without changing the name?

Answer (score 2):

This is not how *Word Automation* works. Check *Word Object Model* ([[MS.Docs]: Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/word/word-home)) for more details.

You should create a `Word.Application` instance, and that will deal with the documents.

I adapted [[SO]: Python - Using win32com.client to accept all changes in Word Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088748/python-using-win32com-client-to-accept-all-changes-in-word-documents) and tested it on a dummy doc for you.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

import sys
import os
import win32com.client as w32comcl


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    doc_path = r"Documento ficticío.docx"
    txt_path = os.path.splitext(doc_path)[0] + ".txt"
    word = w32comcl.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    try:
        word.Visible = False
        doc = word.Documents.Open(os.path.abspath(doc_path))
        try:
            text = doc.Range().Text
            with open(txt_path, "wb") as f:
                f.write(text.encode("utf8"))
        finally:
            doc.Close(False)
    finally:
        word.Application.Quit()
```

**Notes**:

- Changed the variable names a bit
- Added some error handling
- Using [[Python 3]: os.path.**splitext**(*path*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to handle file path name (basically, changing the extension)
- 1<sup>st</sup> line is to avoid getting a *SyntaxError* because of the "**í**" (*0xED*) char ([[Python]: PEP 263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)) - frankly I don't know how come you didn't run into this, since for me, both *Python 3* and *Python 2* are behaving the same

**Output**:

> ```bat
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049179872>dir /b
> code.py
> Documento ficticío.docx
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049179872>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049179872>dir /b
> code.py
> Documento ficticío.docx
> Documento ficticío.txt
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049179872>type "Documento ficticío.txt"
> P├írrafo fictic├¡o0: 1234567890qwertyuioopasdfghjklzxcvbnm.
> ```

Comment: Did this answer your question?