# How can I output Word documents/plaintext with all accepted/rejected track changes?

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, libreoffice

I have a set of .docx documents with text modifications performed with the "track changes" functionality.

For every `source.docx` file in my set, I would like to programmatically run two operations:

1. generate two documents, one with all changes rejected and the other with all changes accepted (the tricky step)
2. convert to plaintext.

In other words, I want to run the following pipelines:

`source.docx` -> `sources-all-changes-rejected.docx` -> `source-all-rejected-plaintext.txt`
`source.docx` -> `sources-all-changes-accepted.docx` -> `source-all-accepted-plaintext.txt`

Is there a way to do this e.g. using `soffice --headless`?

I tried a solution inspired by [Python - Using win32com.client to accept all changes in Word Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088748/python-using-win32com-client-to-accept-all-changes-in-word-documents) . That approach worked, taking care of using absolute paths and saving as txt document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveformat . So I have a function that takes a `pathlib` Path `file_path` and writes plaintext documents as I wanted:

```
def output_track_changed_version(file_path, action):
    
    doc.TrackRevisions = False

    # Delete all comments
    if doc.Comments.Count >= 1:
        doc.DeleteAllComments()

    # Accept/reject all revisions
    doc.Revisions.AcceptAll()
    changed_text = doc.Content.Text
    doc.Undo()
    doc.Revisions.RejectAll()
    original_text = doc.Content.Text

    # [CUT: code to dump changed/original strings to file and then...]

    doc.Close(False, False, False)
    word.Application.Quit()
```

However I don't want to stick to `win32com.client`, preferring a LibreOffice based solution + Python, that can easily be set up on Linux VMs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a solution inspired by [Python - Using win32com.client to accept all changes in Word Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088748/python-using-win32com-client-to-accept-all-changes-in-word-documents) . That approach worked, taking care of using absolute paths and saving as txt document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveformat . So I have a function that takes a `pathlib` Path `file_path` and writes plaintext documents as I wanted:

```
def output_track_changed_version(file_path, action):
    
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
    word.Visible = False

    print(file_path.absolute())
    doc = word.Documents.Open(str(file_path.absolute()))
    
    doc.Activate()
    word.ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False

    # Delete all comments
    if word.ActiveDocument.Comments.Count >= 1:
        word.ActiveDocument.DeleteAllComments()

    # Accept all revisions
    if action == "accept":
        word.ActiveDocument.Revisions.AcceptAll()
        word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(str((Path("accept-all") / file_path.name).absolute())  + ".txt", FileFormat=7)
    elif action == "reject":
        word.ActiveDocument.Revisions.RejectAll()
        word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(str((Path("reject-all") / file_path.name).absolute()) + ".txt", FileFormat=7)

    doc.Close(False)
    word.Application.Quit()
```

However I'd still prefer a `soffice` based solution.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know, whether it solves your problem, but you can use *docx* library (installed with `pip install python-docx` command) to solve this task.

Example:

```
import docx

#rejected changes
doc = docx.Document('source.docx')
doc.save('sources-all-changes-rejected.docx')

#txt
r_text = []
for par in doc.paragraphs:
    r_text.append(par.text)
r_text = '\n'.join(r_text)

filename = 'source-all-rejected-plaintext.txt'
with open(filename, 'w') as r_txt:
    r_txt.write(r_text)

#accepted changes
for par in doc.paragraphs:
    #do changes
    pass

#txt
a_text = []
for par in doc.paragraphs:
    a_text.append(par.text)
a_text = '\n'.join(a_text)

filename = 'source-all-accepted-plaintext.txt'
with open(filename, 'w') as a_txt:
    a_txt.write(a_text)

#docx
doc.save('sources-all-changes-accepted.docx')
```

Then you can loop through all files in the set.

Comment: Hey thanks! One important thing though, is that what needs to happen in the `# do changes` bit is pretty crucial: the changes are already in the source doc (performed with the "track changes" functionality), and I need to reject/accept all changes before outputting the result.