# How to call method ChangeFileOpenDirectory (VBA) using python

Tags: python, win32com

I am trying to map the code from VBA to python. Everything looks perfect but when I came to the ChangeFileOpenDirectory method I had a problem, I really don't know where to call this function.
[image]

Here my code:
Python:

```
import pprint
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
wdExportFormatPDF = 17
wdExportOptimizeForPrint = 0
wdExportAllDocument = 0
wdExportDocumentContent = 0
wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks = 1

word.Visible = True
doc = word.Documents.Open("E:/PYTHON_COMPUTER_VISSION/FINAL_PROJECT/ICO/BAO_CAO.docx")
doc.Active()
word.ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
word.ActiveDocument.Revisions.AcceptAll()
# Delete all comments
if word.ActiveDocument.Comments.Count >= 1:
    word.ActiveDocument.DeleteAllComments()

word.ActiveDocument.Save()
word.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(OutputFileName = "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Test.pdf",
ExportFormat=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport=True, OptimizeFor = wdExportOptimizeForPrint,
Range = wdExportAllDocument, From = 1, To = 1, Itemn = wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps = True,
KeepIRM = True, CreateBookmarks = wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, DocStructureTags = True,
BitmapMissingFonts = True, UseISO19005_1 = False)


doc.Close(False)
word.Application.Quit()
```

VBA:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "NewMacros"
Sub TurnOffMarkup()
Attribute TurnOffMarkup.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "Normal.NewMacros.TurnOffMarkup"
'
' TurnOffMarkup Macro
'
'
    With ActiveWindow.View.RevisionsFilter
        .Markup = wdRevisionsMarkupNone
        .View = wdRevisionsViewFinal
    End With
    ActiveDocument.AcceptAllRevisions
    ActiveDocument.Save
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\BAO_CAO.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
        wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
        wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    **ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\"**
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Anyone who has experienced this problem please give me advice. Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't see what the point of `ChangeFileOpenDirectory` here in the code, but in python, to change the reference directory, you could look at the library `os` and the method [`chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)

Comment: Thank you so much @Ben.T-san. About python we no need to use ChangeFileOpenDirectory. The ExportAsFixedFormat method already allows the file to be stored in the specified directory, so there is no need for the ChangeFileOpenDirectory method. I just discovered this.

Comment: I didn't sleep to investigate it on the internet and then found nothing, then I tried to run the code without the ChangeFileOpenDirectory method and the results were surprising. It was just as I wanted.